# How to exclude commas from word boundaries

Tags: python, regex

I'm attempting to parse thousand/million/hundred million values out of plaintext. I need to exclude commas and decimals from the typical word boundaries so 1,000,000 doesn't return multiple hits. I need my values to be exclusive and only match at the highest number. How do I recreate word boundary functionality that ignores commas and decimals?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the regex/code you've tried so far?

Comment: I can, but would it really be all that helpful to have a huge list of messy regex patterns without much context?

Comment: The "generic" answer to "how do I capture a word without excluding commas and decimals" would probably be "capture anything besides whitespace", which would be `r'\S*'`. Or "capture alphanumerics, commas, and full stops", which would be `r'[\w,.]*'`. But to give an answer better tailored to your particular use case, it would be helpful to know what you have so far.

Comment: Thanks for the help. YOGO's answer actually solved the problem for me, and honestly my tried patterns are way too big and confusing so I don't think it's worth posting them because no one wants to try to parse those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Word boudary \b does not include commas, it includes: (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W) , \w represents: [a-zA-Z0-9_] and \W is like NOT \w in this way: [^a-zA-Z0-9_]

Maybe you need this : [\d,.]+

It will match 1,000,000 or 1,000.000 ...

Comment: This works, thanks! I'm kind of approaching regex laterally, so I have a lot to learn refining my patterns!